# What's the different between these 2 mysql queries? one using left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I see people using LEFT JOIN in their mysql queries to fetch data from two tables. But I normally do it without left join. Is there any differences besides the syntax, e.g. performance?

Here's my normal query style:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as tbl1, table2 as tbl2 WHERE tbl1.id=tbl2.table_id
```

as compared to

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as tbl1 LEFT JOIN table2 as tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id
```

Personally I prefer the first style...hmm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a left join, all values from table1 are selected even if table2 does not contain the same id.

Your normal query style can be compared to an "inner join".

Comment: so assuming if i was comparing the normal style query and one that uses inner join, is there any difference or reason why I should use one over the other? thanks :)